# Copy-paste password "macro-style"?

Tags: scripts, password, paste

I've run into some programs that don't let me copy-paste text into them. This is a problem, as I use a password manager ([KeePass](http://keepass.info/)), and not being able to copy-paste my password into the login screen (as is the case with Minecraft) is a problem.

I could bypass this by using shorter passwords that are easy to type, but I'd rather ask you fine people if you know any software that "pastes" text by, say, issuing the key presses as a macro command. For example, pasting "agiK" would execute a-g-i-holdshift-k-releaseshift as key presses.

Anyone know of such software?

Comment: There are some tools that bind custom scripts to keyboard shortcuts. You could use such a script to write the password at the current cursor position. One example would be AutoKey, or its more modern port [autokey-py3](https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey-py3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any way, ***never*** copy-paste a password from a plain-text source.

The script below can be used to paste your password in an entry of a Zenity dialog. Subsequently, after pressing <kbd>OK</kbd>, the script will type out what is entered (or pasted) after three seconds.

Although I wouldn't see how, I am not sure if there are any security issues with what you want, so use it at your own risk.

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
try:
    password = subprocess.check_output([
        "zenity", "--entry", "--title=Password",
        "--text=Paste your password below"]).decode("utf-8")
    time.sleep(3)
    for c in password:
        subprocess.call(["xdotool", "type", c])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an emty file, save it as `pasteword.py`
3. Test-run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/pasteword.py
   ```

   within three seconds, click in the entry where you have to enter the password, it will be typed out by `xdotool`
4. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/pasteword.py
   ```

#### Note

If you find the three seconds not the most convenient value, you can change it in the line:

```
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: You went above and beyond the call of duty. It works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: "In any way, never copy-paste a password from a plain-text source." As much as I agree, my generated Mojang (minecraft) password is unique to that account, and I don't really care if someone hacks into my Mojang account since it hasn't connected any payment details.

Comment: @Mossmyr True of course, but in general, I wouldn't .